# Update single data in firebase real time database xamarin forms

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, updates

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database and I want to modify a single data.

Here's my DB's Json:

```
"Users" : {
    "h31QEhvv4pdzbyqHkwyrd8MI5Fu2" : {
      "Books" : {
        "codebook0" : {
          "Author" : "De Amicis",
          "Cover" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com....",
          "Genre" : "Children",
          "Status" : "Reading",
          "Title" : "Cuore"
        }
```

I retrive readings books in a listview with this method:

```
public async Task<List<User>> GetReadings()
        {
            return (await firebase
              .Child("Users")
              .Child(auth.CurrentUser())
              .Child("Books")
              .OrderBy("Status")
              .EqualTo("Reading")
              .OnceAsync<User>()).Select(item =>
              new User {
                  Title = item.Object.Title,
                  Author = item.Object.Author,
                  Genre = item.Object.Genre,
                  Cover = item.Object.Cover
              }).ToList();
        }
```

Now I have a Button in the single viewcell and, by clicking on it, I want to change the book status to "read".

I tried this way:

```
public async Task UpdateStatus(string status)
         {
             var toUpdateStatus = (await firebase
               .Child("Users")
               .Child(auth.CurrentUser())
               .Child("Books")
               .OnceAsync<User>()).Where(a => a.Object.Status == status).FirstOrDefault();

             await firebase
               .Child("Users")
               .Child(auth.CurrentUser())
               .Child("Books")
               .Child(toUpdateStatus.Key)
               .PutAsync(new User() { Status = status });
         }

private async void ReadClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;

            var book = (Utente)btn.BindingContext;

            var status = book.Status;
            await UpdateStatus("read");
            
        }
```

But, obviously, it doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

DB Json

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "h31QEhvv4pdzbyqHkwyrd8MI5Fu2" : {
      "Books" : {
        "codebook0" : {
          "Status" : "Reading",
          "Title" : "abc"
        },
        "codebook1" : {
          "Status" : "Reading",
          "Title" : "sdf"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will have to pass both old and new status.

```
await UpdateStatus("Reading","read");
```

Now UpdateStatus Method is

```
public async Task UpdateStatus(string oldStatus, string newStatus)
    {
        var toUpdateStatus = (await firebase
          .Child("Users")
          .Child("h31QEhvv4pdzbyqHkwyrd8MI5Fu2")
          .Child("Books")
          .OnceAsync<User>()).Where(a => a.Object.Status == oldStatus).FirstOrDefault();

        toUpdateStatus.Object.Status = newStatus;

        await firebase
          .Child("Users")
          .Child("h31QEhvv4pdzbyqHkwyrd8MI5Fu2")
          .Child("Books")
          .Child(toUpdateStatus.Key)
          .PutAsync(toUpdateStatus.Object);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Unfortunately it doesn't work, it gives me NullReferenceException at .Child(toUpdateStatus.Key) row.

Comment: var status = book.status. Check the status value. It should be "Reading" and check auth.CurrentUser() it should be "h31QEhvv4pdzbyqHkwyrd8MI5Fu2" according to your posted json. It will not give NullReferenceException. I checked it.

Comment: Yes, it should not, but it does. I've done it exactly like this and it gives me exception at toUpdateStatus.Key, like if it is nothing in it

Comment: I updated my answer. I created same Json data posted in my answer (same as yours) in firebase database and called UpdateStatus method and values is updating in the database.